# How to call a function after Highchart animation complete In Angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am not able to call a function in ploatOption-> series > animation -> complete

Sample code is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-variwide-faharz-ubhknv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
ploatOption: {
series: {
animation: { duration: 200,
complete: function() {

//Call ChartHighlight() here

} } } },
```

How can I call a function (in this case "ChartHighlight()" inside a complete function? Please refer to the sample code link.

Comment: (Use block Markdown formatting for several lines of code - you can preserve indentation that way).

Comment: Should `ploatOption` be `plotOption`?

Comment: Thank you halfer for the reply, while creating the sample project by mistake I wrote  "ploatOption" .:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

1. `ploatOption` must be [`plotOptions`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions).
2. There is no `series.animation.complete` property. You need to use [`series.events.afterAnimate`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.afterAnimate).
3. Use need to use either `bind(this)` or arrow functions in callback to preserve the meaning of `this`. More info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/6513921).
4. You are initializing the chart before the series is initialized in the `BindBarChart()` function. Wrap it in `*ngIf` to initialize it after the `chartOptions` property is defined.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    animation: {
      duration: 200
    },
    events: {
      afterAnimate: () => this.ChartHighlight()
    }
  }
},
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!!chartOptions">
  <highcharts-chart 
    style="display: inline-block" 
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts" 
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [(update)]="updatechart" 
    [callbackFunction]="chartcallback"
  ></highcharts-chart>
</ng-container>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-variwide-faharz-pzdjc6?file=src/app/app.component.html).